# What are the two "one frame" pictures in EP 7, Season 5 of Breaking Bad?

Tags: breaking-bad

Just noticed that there's a one-frame scene in the *Breaking Bad* episode S05E07, after Jesse watching Skyler walked away in her car-washing warehouse. Just like the stuff in the movie "Fight Club". Is there anyone taken a screen shot of that scene?

Comment: Answer: There probably is! Better question: What does it show and what does it mean?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't torrent these episodes, and the brief flashes are actually bit of adverts that were cut out? :-/

Comment: I watched them online. (iqiyi.com) I don't use BT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably at this time (11:40).

[image]

Watching it on Netflix, there is nothing particular. Just after this scene, the image fades and switches to the (funny) lawyer at the bank scene.

Answer (score 3):

I've just checked and that's exactly where it fades to black for an advert break. It's clear you've seen a flash of an advert that wasn't edited out properly, and thought it was deliberate.